# Running ERC20 contract on RSK

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, ethereum-vm

*Disclaimer: originally [asked on the ETH SE site](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/running-erc20-contract-on-rsk), but advised to post here.*

I have been reading about [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/) lately and was wondering about the compatibility and possibilities, so I wanted to ask for some basic info in case there's someone more knowledgeable.

I have a smart contract running on the Ethereum network (and more to come). The contract is based on the ERC20 standard. So, this smart contract, with its setup today, would it be possible to make it use the RSK network instead of Ethereum?

If yes, what could be the pros/cons (eg. cheaper/faster transactions) and whether it would make sense to do the transition?

If not for the current contract, then maybe for future ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, this smart contract, with its setup today, would it be possible to make it use the RSK network instead of Ethereum?

Yes. https://developers.rsk.co/tutorials/ethereum-devs/port-ethereum-dapps/

RSK Bridge can also be helpful for users to swap tokens: https://developers.rsk.co/tools/tokenbridge/

> If yes, what could be the pros/cons (eg. cheaper/faster transactions) and whether it would make sense to do the transition?

There are lot of differences. You can read this medium post which explains few technical differences and development of Rootstock: https://medium.com/iovlabs-innovation-stories/similarities-and-differences-between-rsk-and-ethereum-e480655eff37

Scaling is the biggest advantage in using a Bitcoin Sidechain for such experiments.

Rootstock resources: https://github.com/john-light/RSK