# Making and trading tokens with bitcoin like with solidity and ethereum metamask

Tags: script, taproot, bitcoin-economy, tokens

So I've learned how to make erc 20 tokens using solidity on the ethereum blockchain and move them around with metamask.

Is there a similar process for making bitcoin tokens and moving those around with a wallet like metamask?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a similar process for making bitcoin tokens

1. Colored Coins: Most of the tokens use OP_RETURN but it's not required

Example: [BSQ](https://bisq.wiki/BSQ) used in Bisq DAO and DEX

2. Omni layer: This project used fake bitcoin addresses, multisig and OP_RETURN to solve the problem. It was used by USDT token for long time until fees on Bitcoin became an issue.

https://github.com/OmniLayer/spec/blob/master/OmniSpecification-v0.6.adoc#smart-property

3. Counterparty: This project also used OP_RETURN and issuing assets was possible with it.

https://counterparty.io/docs/create_token/

There might be few other projects that allowed tokens to be created in which on-chain Bitcoin transactions were required. This does not scale and there was never a standard like ERC20 on Bitcoin. Users and developers realized it's better if we do this stuff using layer 2 or off-chain.

There are 3 projects that are mostly used for layer 2 in Bitcoin: Lightning Network, Liquid Sidechain and Rootstock sidechain.

There are no standards or BOLT to create tokens on LN right now. I had discussed this on LN dev mailing list few days back: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2021-October/003305.html

However, multiple projects are working to make this possible including Omni BOLT, RGB and Synonym. [Submarine swaps](https://docs.lightning.engineering/the-lightning-network/lightning-overview/understanding-submarine-swaps) are already possible so issuing assets would make things better.

Issuing assets on Liquid is possible using `issueasset` RPC. It's very easy and everything works similar to Bitcoin Core in Elements Core. You can read more about it here: https://help.blockstream.com/hc/en-us/articles/900005127583-How-do-I-issue-an-asset-on-Liquid-

Creating tokens on Rootstock sidechain is similar to Ethereum. You can even port ERC20 to Rootstock:

[Running ERC20 contract on RSK](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103165/running-erc20-contract-on-rsk/)

> and moving those around with a wallet like metamask?

Metamask is mainly used because it has a browser extension/add-on. There are different open source wallets for Bitcoin, LN and Bitcoin sidechains. I don't consider browser extensions to be secure way of doing transactions however you can use the below wallets in browser:

| Lightning | Liquid | Rootstock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [lightning-browser-extension](https://github.com/getAlby/lightning-browser-extension) | [Marina](https://github.com/vulpemventures/marina) | [Liquality](https://liquality.io/) |
| [Joule](https://github.com/joule-labs/joule-extension) |  | [Metamask](https://developers.rsk.co/wallet/use/metamask/) |